# How to set column conditionally in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been working on a spread sheet for work for about a week and a half now and have been stuck in the same place. I am working on something for payroll purpose. So A1 would have an employee name as would the rest of the column. B2 would have that specific employees hours worked.

for example.

```
  A              B
1 Doe, John C    6.65
```

I need a formula that will automatically move anyone that has hours greater than 0 to column E, along with their worked. hours.

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: Just set E1 to =IF(B1>0,A1,"") and copy down the column. Or =IF(B1>0,CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1),"") to include both name and hours

Comment: @samgak: why not posting your comment as an answer? seems the right solution, isn't it?

Comment: @NirMH ok, done. I was actually composing an answer when this question started attracting mad downvotes, so I just posted a comment instead. But I guess I may as well answer it.

Comment: @samgak: while the community thinks the question is not "respected" enough, it is still a question (not yet closed) - so it is worth an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the name in column E and the worked hours in column F then set E1 to

```
=IF(B1>0,A1,"")
```

and set F1 to

```
=IF(B1>0,B1,"")
```

If you want the name and worked hours both in column E then set E1 to

```
=IF(B1>0,CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1),"")
```

and copy down the column.

`IF(condition, expression if true, expression if false)` allows you to set cells based on a logical condition. `CONCATENATE` allows you to join the contents of multiple cells (or expressions) together as a string.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! sorry for the confusion.